# Why django form valdation error does not work in my form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-validation

I want to show user validation error but seems that this is not working in my login form here is the code
my forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False, label='Remember Me',help_text='Keep me logged in.',widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user doesn't exist")
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect Password")
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User no longer Active")
        return super(LoginForm,self).clean(*args,**kwargs)
```

my views.py for login

```
def my_login(request):
    if 'next' in request.GET:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 'To Continue, Please login here!')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            remember_me = form.cleaned_data['remember_me']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if not remember_me:
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)
                    return redirect('accounts:home')
                else:
                    request.session.set_expiry(1209600)
                    return redirect('accounts:home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Please check your credentials.')
            return redirect('accounts:login')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, "login.html", {'form': form})
```

i know i am redirecting the form if form credential is wrong but if i don't i will throw error didn't return a httpresponse it return none instead also want to what is the best way to redirect or show exact validation error of which credential is wrong

Comment: There is no `else` case for `if user`. That is the test that is failing, and for that casey you thus should implement logic.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i want to show user validation right if username is correct & password is wrong password is incoorect & if username is worng no user exist i updted that as you told instead of redirecting i want to show user validation error i